# Eclipse: Set Debug Configuration used for Auto-Build

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, run-configuration

Maybe i explain what should be achieved first - maybe the attempted solution is wrong:

We have some Maven Projects that are assembled into a final war file. We use Maven profiles to define the actual Variables required for different environments (such as "local", "staging", "demo", "production" etc...)

For the Projects we are using Gitflow to manage releases. This leads to the problem that version changes done on a release or hotfix branch are always merged back to the pom of the develop-branch. (Excluding the pom obviously is no solution, other changes are supposed to be merged)

So we want to pass the information about which version of which project should be used when invoking the build. From a logical point of view this seems to be the most accurate position for this purpose.

Even if it is not recommended to set versions in the pom a variable, it seems to do exactly what we need.

For example, building the project with `mvn -Dplugin1=1.0.0.0 -Dplugin2=1.3.4.5 clean install` will build the whole Project perfectly fine. For the dev-environment it should always refer the latest version, which is called "dev" in our case.

So we made a Run configuration for the arguments `mvn -Dplugin1=dev -Dplugin2=dev clean install`.

#### The actual problem

How can we advice Eclipse to use *our* Run-Configuration when doing an automatic maven-build?

- If I select "Run Configuration > dev" it builds as expected.
- If I just clean the project and let it auto-build, eclipse builds without args, leading to a corrupt project, cause now all the versions are "null".